# How to parse html inside xml's tag

Tags: php, parsing, rss, domdocument

I need help in getting data from `description` tag where it consists of `<a>`, `<img>`and some text. The xml I am trying to parse is [this](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/rssfeeds/2886704.cms)

I managed to get all the data I need, except for `description` tag where I got `<a>` tag along with description text. What I need is `img`'s src and the description text.

My code :

```
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
        /*$test = $node->getElementsByTagName('description');
        $test = $test->item(0)->textContent;*/
        var_dump($test);
        exit;
         $nodes = $node->getElementsByTagName('content');


         if(!is_object($nodes) || $nodes === null || $nodes->length==0){

                $linkthumbNode = $node->getElementsByTagName('image');


                if(isset($linkthumbNode) && $linkthumbNode->length >0){
                        $linkthumb=$linkthumbNode->item(0)->nodeValue;

                        if(empty($linkthumb)||$linkthumb == " "){


                            $linkthumb = $linkthumbNode->item(0)->getAttribute('src');

                        }

                    }else{

                        $linkthumb = "NO IMAGE";
                 }

         }else{

             $linkthumb = $nodes->item(0)->getAttribute('url');
         }

         $title = $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
         $desc = $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->textContent;
         $link = $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue;
         $img = $linkthumb;
         $date = $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate');
         if(isset($date) && $date->length >0){
            $date = $date->item(0)->nodeValue;
         }else{
            $date = "no date provided";

         }


        $item = array ( 
            'title' => $title,
            'desc' =>  $desc,
            'link' => $link,
            'img' => $img,
            'date' => $date,
            );
        array_push($feed, $item);
    }
```

the xml description tag is :

```
<description>
<a href="http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/life-style/health-fitness/diet/9-food-combos-to-make-you-lean/articleshow/20984744.cms"><img border="0" hspace="10" align="left" style="margin-top:3px;margin-right:5px;" src="http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/photo/20984744.cms" /></a>Nine food combinations that will make staying healthy and looking fit easier
</description>
```

what I need: `http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/photo/20984744.cms` as image  and `Nine food combinations that will make staying healthy and looking fit easier` as my description.

Can someone help me? I'm not that great at PHP and parsing XML.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am a little late to the party, but if an answer is still needed, check out my solution. I use PHP [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and regular expressions since I haven't found a simple way to get the needed data using only XML-extensions.

```
$rss = file_get_contents('https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/rssfeeds/2886704.cms');
$feed = new DOMDocument();
$feed->loadXML($rss);

$items = array();

foreach($feed->getElementsByTagName('item') as $item) {
    $arr = array();
    foreach($item->childNodes as $child) {
        if($child->nodeName === 'title' || $child->nodeName === 'link') $arr[$child->nodeName] = $child->nodeValue; 
        if($child->nodeName === 'pubDate') $arr['date'] = $child->nodeValue; 
        if($child->nodeName === 'description') {
            preg_match('/(?<=src=[\'\"])(.+)(?=[\'\"])/i', $child->nodeValue, $matches);
            $arr['img'] = $matches[0];
            preg_match('/[^>]+$/i', $child->nodeValue, $matches);
            $arr['desc'] = $matches[0];
        }
    }
    array_push($items, $arr);
}
print_r($items);
```

The output is like this and seems to be what you needed:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [title] => 5 reasons you get sore after sex [img] => https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/photo/61101815.cms [desc] => Sometimes, a super-filmy, almost-perfect sex leaves you all euphoric but only to end with soreness later. So, what is it that is going wrong? Can it be remedied? [link] => https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/life-style/health-fitness/health-news/5-reasons-you-get-sore-after-sex/life-style/health-fitness/health-news/5-reasons-you-get-sore-after-sex/photostory/61101724.cms [date] => Mon, 16 Oct 2017 10:21:27 GMT )...
```